# Standard deviation of number between n rows and n columns of 3 arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, standard-deviation

I want to find standard deviation of every 3 values of every array with `numpy`

For example, I have array as follows,

```
dcc = [[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9] [11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88 99][0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9]]
```

I want to find standard deviation of every 3 values of every array. Basically in the output, the first value will be standard deviation of "1 2 3 11 22 33 0.1 0.2 0.3" and the second value will be standard deviation of "4 5 6 44 55 66 0.4 0.5 0.6" and so on.

I have tried a lot of things but any of them doesn't seem to work. Please help.

Comment: Can you provide some examples of the things you've tried?

Comment: I have all three list combined in dcc, I tried taking standard deviation along 3 axis as follows which didn't work standard_dev = np.std(dcc,axis=[0,1,2], ddof=1)

Comment: I have all three list combined in dcc which looks like this: dcc = [[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9] [11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88 99] [0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9]] .I tried taking standard deviation along 3 axis as follows which didn't work standard_dev = np.std(dcc,axis=[0,1,2], ddof=1)

Comment: First, these are `numpy` arrays, not lists.  Second, you do not have them organized into axes; rather, you're asking to take the `std` of re-organized slices of the arrays.  Look up how to slice and recombine arrays to get your data into the form you need.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections. I know I have to slice and rearrange the arrays and then recombine them such that I get required elements in one array and then I can simply find out the standard-deviation. The only problem is I am not able to find a way to do the slice-rearrange-recombine part effectively. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I got your question correctly;

```
import numpy as np

dcc = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],[11, 22 ,33, 44, 55, 66,77, 88,99],\
            [0.1, 0.2,0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8 ,0.9]])

my_stds=[np.std(np.concatenate(dcc.reshape(3, 3, 3)[:,i]), axis=0) for i in range(len(dcc))]
my_stds
>>> [11.167910378500638, 25.242204517214596, 39.860451020473356]
```